# Sending mail with mailgun through node.js - requested URL not found

Tags: node.js, mailgun

my stack: node.js with Express 4.x
mailgun module: [mailgun-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun-js)

I currently developing on my local machine and trying to send some simple confirmation email as shown in this module example:

```
var api_key = 'key-xxx';
var domain = 'http://mg.xxx.com/';
var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({apiKey: api_key, domain: domain});

var data = {
      from: 'Billing <no-reply@mydomain.com>',
      to: data.email, 
      subject: 'Thanks for buying ' + data.product,
      text: 'You can create your plan right now or visist http://www.someurl.com later.'
    };

    mailgun.messages().send(data, function (err, body) {
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }
      console.log("mail sent", body);
    });
```

According to this example this should work, unfortunate I keep getting the following error :

```
{ [Error: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server.</p><p>If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
] statusCode: 404 }
```

When I change the domain to : `"mg.xxx.com"` without the http then I get this error:

```
{ [Error: Domain not found: md.xxx.com] statusCode: 404 }
```

I don't know where to start debugging this - maybe it doesnt work locally?

**Already fixed - the problem was that I wrote md instead of mg**

Comment: the domain should be a subdomain of mailgun: `var domain = 'mydomain.mailgun.org';`

Comment: so it shoud be the domain i registered.mailgun.org ? Oo

Comment: Yes, you should also sign your domain up with mailgun

Comment: I already did I think. I registered my domain there and did all the DNS settings for my subdomain md.xxx.com

Comment: then you should have a URL that mailgun gives you to use. What you are doing is accessing the mailgun API via node with this package.

Comment: Just the code I published. It works now.. I made a stupid mistake with mixing up md with mg.. the correct Domain is md.mydomain.com. Thank you for your help anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a typo that I made at the variable declaration:

```
var domain = 'http://mg.xxx.com/';
```

correct:

```
var domain = 'http://md.xxx.com/';
```

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `'http://mg.xxx.com/'` is the mailgun base API URL.  To send a message, you'll want to POST to address `'http://mg.xxx.com/messages'`.  Mailgun has [documentation for curl](https://documentation.mailgun.com/quickstart-sending.html#send-via-api) that you can practice with:

```
curl -s --user 'api:YOUR_API_KEY' \
https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages \
-F from='Excited User <mailgun@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>' \
-F to=YOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME \
-F to=bar@example.com \
-F subject='Hello' \
-F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'
```

Answer (score 2):

When you signup, you are given one domain like below

```
Sandbox<**somebignumberhere**>.Mailgun.Org
```

Mention this in `var domain = 'Sandbox<**somebignumberhere**>.Mailgun.Org;`

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem, but my solution was to define another endpoint for mailgun api as my domain was created in EU region.

Endpoint for this region is: `https://api.eu.mailgun.net`

After this change, all started to work.